# Calling Ansible tags in a specific order

Tags: ansible

I have an Ansible job where I am calling multiple Shell scripts, and each shell script has its own tag.

So, I have 5 scripts in total with 5 tags.

My Tag 1 & tag 2 are the first that has to go and then only the running the next 3 tags would make sense. If someone runs tag 3 directly, I want the pipeline to fail.
How can I add a dependency for the tags 3,4 & 5 that tags 1 & 2 has to run 1st.

Please advise.

My current `.yml` file is like this.

```yaml
- name: Task 1
      shell: "/tmp/1.sh -a {{ IN.1}} -b {{ IN.2 }}"
      register: Task1.sh
      tags: task1
- name: Task 2
      shell: "/tmp/2.sh -a {{ IN.2}} -b {{ IN.2 }}"
      register: Task2.sh
      tags: task2
.
.
.
.
- name: Task 5
      shell: "/tmp/5.sh -a {{ IN.1}} -b {{ IN.2 }}"
      register: Task5.sh
      tags: task5
```

Comment: All of this does not make much sense. Tasks will be executed in the order you defined them. If a task in the flow absolutely needs an other one to run before it, don't implement a feature (i.e. tags) that will let users skip it. There is nothing such as "tag dependency". This all looks like an ansible miss-usage. My 2 cent: forget the tags one moment and explain precisely what are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

A rough but one-hundred-percent solution is to add commands to run the first scripts in the task, not to tie to tasks and tags:

```
- name: Task 5
      shell: |
        /tmp/1.sh -a {{ IN.1}} -b {{ IN.2 }}
        /tmp/2.sh -a {{ IN.2}} -b {{ IN.2 }}
        /tmp/5.sh -a {{ IN.1}} -b {{ IN.2 }}
      register: Task5.sh
      tags: task5
```